# Programatically change Internet Explorer Proxy Including the Password Without Restarting ie in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer, proxy

Is it even possible?

I know a way to do so is to change the registry. However there has to be a better way.

Shared Sub EnableProxy1()

```
Dim regKey As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey

regKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings", True)
regKey.SetValue("ProxyEnable", True, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord)
regKey.SetValue("ProxyServer", proxyhandler.proxyFedtoInternetExplorer, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.String)
regKey.SetValue("ProxyOverride", "<local>", Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.String)
regKey.Close()
```

End Sub

Shared Sub DisableProxy()
    Dim regKey As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey

```
regKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings", True)

regKey.SetValue("ProxyEnable", False, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord)

regKey.Close()
```

End Sub

Doing this has 2 weaknesses

1. I need to restart internet explorer
2. I need to change the username and password of the proxy by manipulating windows directly.

I want a method that's better and direct. Any ways?

Comment: The system wide proxy? why currently does vb.net require a restart?

Comment: The ie proxy. The ie must be restarted.

Comment: Sorry the title should have been Programatically change Internet Explorer Proxy Including the Password Without Restarting IE in vb.net

Answer (score 1):

```
Imports Microsoft.Win32
Public Class ProxySetting
    Public Function IsProxyEnabled() As Boolean
        Try
            Dim Regs As RegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree)
            If Regs.GetValue("ProxyEnable") <> Nothing Then
                If Regs.GetValue("ProxyEnable").ToString() = "0" Then
                    Return False
                Else
                    Return True
                End If
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function

    Public Function GetProxyServer() As String
        Try
            Dim Regs As RegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree)
            If Regs.GetValue("ProxyServer") <> Nothing Then
                Return Regs.GetValue("ProxyServer").ToString()
            Else
                Return ""
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return ""
        End Try
    End Function

    Public Sub DisableProxy()
        Dim regKey As RegistryKey
        Try
            regKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings", True)
            regKey.SetValue("ProxyEnable", False, RegistryValueKind.DWord)
            regKey.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub SetProxy(ByVal ServerName As String, ByVal port As Integer)
        Try
            Dim regkey1 As RegistryKey
            regkey1 = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings", True)
            regkey1.SetValue("ProxyServer", ServerName + ":" + port.ToString(), RegistryValueKind.Unknown)
            regkey1.SetValue("ProxyEnable", True, RegistryValueKind.DWord)
            regkey1.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Add some explanation.